# RingCentral integration with event subscriptions for individual users

Tags: ringcentral

I have an application that we are going to integrate with RingCentral.  I'd like to get event subscriptions for each individual logged in user, so that the application can respond to call events specific to the individual user that's logged in.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some info on how to do it quickly. I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it seems pretty simple to me. You'd simply call the endpoint (https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/accountId/call-log
), pass through a tilde for accountId, and you'd get the call log for the logged in user.

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Log/readCompanyCallLog has a lot more details.